# How to transform CSV rows with the same keys into hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I have parsed the .csv file and received the following headers:

```
"Date":"Start" "Date":"Due" "Amount":"Total" "Amount":"Left"
```

There are values for each. I need to map it to hash dynamically in the following way:

```
{date => {start: value, due: value}, amount => {total: value, left: value}}
```

Please, could you suggest a way. I've tried to use it as an array like:

```
[["Date", "Start"], ["Date", "Due"], ["Amount", "Total"], ["Amount", "Left"]]
```

and then

```
.each_slice(2)
```

but after that I got stuck. Thanks in advance

Comment: are the headers like `date, start, date, due, amount, total, amount, left`? or `start, due, total, left`?

Comment: ``` date, start, date, due, amount, total, amount, left ``` like that

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like:

```
rows.map do |row|
  { 
    date: { start: row[1], end: row[3] },
    amount: { total: row[4], left: row[6] }
  }
end
```

Comment: thanks. I didn't mentioned I need to do so dynamically as I have more keys, those were just  a part of them, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
headers = [["Date", "Start"], ["Date", "Due"], ["Amount", "Total"], ["Amount", "Left"]]
values= [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

```
Hash[headers.zip(values)].each_with_object({}) do |(keys, value), memo|
  pk = keys.first.downcase.to_sym
  memo[pk] ||= {}
  memo[pk][keys.last.downcase.to_sym] = value
end
```

Output:

```
=> {:date=>{:start=>1, :due=>2}, :amount=>{:total=>3, :left=>4}}
```